# PHP Display business hours of operation

Tags: php

I am trying to display a notice when a business is open on a Wordpress-based website and pulling the information from a database. The data is stored simply as opening/closing times for each day, as separate database entries. It is fairly straight forward when the hours are within a single day. But for a bar/restaurant, it becomes complex because the closing time is technically in the next day. I'll use Tuesday as an example.

```
$tuesdayopen = strtotime("10:00");
$tuesdayclose = strtotime("23:00");
$now = strtotime("now");

if ($now >= $tuesdayopen && $now <= $tuesdayclose) {
    echo "We are open!";
} else {
    echo "We are closed!";
}
```

So this works fine as is. And if the closing time is into next day, I have an inelegant solution for that too.

```
$tuesdayopen = strtotime("10:00");
$tuesdayclose = strtotime("02:00");
$now = strtotime("now");

if ($tuesdayclose >= strtotime("00:00") && $tuesdayclose <= strtotime("04:00")):
    $tuesdayclose = strtotime("+1 day", $tuesdayclose);
endif;

if ($now >= $tuesdayopen && $now <= $tuesdayclose) {
    echo "We are open!";
} else {
    echo "We are closed!";
}
```

So where is my problem? The problem is when $now ends up being after midnight. So if someone visits the page Tuesday night, after midnight, it is technically Wednesday morning. Which means that my full script would move on to Wednesday. I need it to recognize that it is between midnight and 4AM and as such, use the previous days open/closing times to determine if it is open (but only if the closing time is after midnight, otherwise moving on to Wednesday is the right thing to do). Hopefully I explained that well. I have tried writing something myself, but the code is a bloated mess and ultimately doesn't work. So I won't bother including it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create an array with times that the place is open and loop through that. Additional advantage is that if a place closes during lunch for instance, it's easy to add.

Note that I normalize the time to count seconds from monday 00:00, regardless it the time is in the future or past.

```
<?php

// Normalize time to count from 0
function timeOfWeek($time) {
  if (!is_int($time)) $time = strtotime($time) ;
  $secondsInWeek = (7 * 24 * 3600);
  return (($time - strtotime('monday 00:00')) % $secondsInWeek + $secondsInWeek) % $secondsInWeek;
}

function isOpen($opened, $time) {
  $time = timeOfWeek($time);

  foreach ($opened as $openday) {
    list($open, $close) = $openday;

    if ($open < $close) { 
      if ($time > $open && $time < $close) return true;
    } else {
      if ($time > $open || $time < $close) return true; // Special case sunday -> monday
    }
  }

  return false;
}

$opened = array();
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('monday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('monday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('tuesday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('tuesday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('wednesday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('wednesday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('thursday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('thursday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('friday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('saturday 01:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('saturday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('sunday 01:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('sunday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('monday 01:00'));

$open = isOpen($opened, time());
var_dump($open);
```

Comment: Looks awesome, but it's not working. I'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function timeOfWeek(). I'm probably just missing something.

Comment: Yup, I'm an idiot. Got it working, now just customizing it to my needs. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, should not use a function before it's defined :s

Comment: Ok, this definitely works. Now I just need to link it to the variables coming out of my database. I've modified my database entries to match this, so "monday 10:00" and "tuesday 02:00", etc. etc. But if I try modifying the array so ('monday 10:00') becomes ($mondayopen) or ('$mondayopen'), it no longer works. What am I missing? And thanks again for your help. As you can see from my PHP skills, there's a reason I use Wordpress. :)

Comment: Please post a new question with what you have so far. (Can't write code in comments.)

Comment: Whatever is happening is not related to the database. Placing this inside my Wordpress template file results in it not working, even if using static values. Not entirely sure how to troubleshoot that though.

Comment: @user1941721 Post a new question with the code you have. A wordpress expert will probably come to your aid. I really wouldn't now.

Answer (score -2):

simply you can convert timezone to yourTimeZone-4h!

Comment: That might do it, thanks. I'll start writing and let you know.